# Cake - Auth Component Username Login

Tags: cakephp

Currently, the Auth component allows a space at the end of the username for login (it accepts 'username' or 'username ') - How can I make it so that if there is an added space at the end it will be viewed as an incorrect username

Comment: Why? Whitespace around posted data strings contain no meaning (in 99% of all cases), so it can simply be ignored. I always trim any and all incoming post/get data regarding whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to do your own check before calling the Auth component's login function:

```
if(trim($this->request->data['User']['username']) != $this->request->data['User']['username'])
{
      //Disallow login
}
```